# DimpleJS - Get original data in getTooltipText callback

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

#### Goal

I would like to pass some extra data along to dimple for display in the tooltip.

Right now I show the number of products on the shelf and the time at which they were counted. I would also like to show other data in the hover tooltip, specifically the name of the person who counted the product on the shelf.

#### Issue

The callback for `getTooltipText` only gets back a event which does not seem to contain the original data. I went into the dimple source to see if the original data could be added to the event, but I was unable to find it in the event stack. I know I could do a lookup in my original array for data with the same x,y values, but there it needs to take into account data with the same count/timestamp.

Any other suggestions on how I could do this?

#### Solution

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/issues/152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just answered the GitHub issue for this, but for reference here is the answer:

Because dimple does aggregation on the dataset, it ignores any fields which do not form part of its definition of a data point. In your case you need to include any additional fields you would like to reference in the first parameter of the series. For example if I had a bar chart of SKUs and sales volume:

```
var c = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
c.addCategoryAxis("x", "SKU");
c.addMeasureAxis("y", "Sales Volume");
c.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
c.draw();
```

And I wanted to add brand owner, brand, price tier and pack size in the tool tip I would define it using the first parameter of the `addSeries` method. NB. One caveat here is that the last element of an array passed in here is used to define colours, so in the example below I pass an empty string to ensure all bars continue to be coloured the same. I could choose any of the other values, or SKU depending on the effect I want to achieve.

```
var c = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
c.addCategoryAxis("x", "SKU");
c.addMeasureAxis("y", "Sales Volume");
c.addSeries(["Brand Owner", "Brand", "Price Tier", "Pack Size", ""], dimple.plot.bar);
c.draw();
```

This will add those fields into the default tooltip and also make them available should you wish to use them in a custom tooltip.